# chaining c++ streams

Tags: c++, iostream

I was thinking of "chaining" a couple of c++ iostreams toghether to filter input twice. I'm using gzstreams to read zlib compressed files and I was thinking of coding a stream that reads from a stream and performs encoding conversions. Perhaps by passing an opened stream as constructor parameter... How do you think this could be best accomplished?

Comment: what do you mean by "chaining"?

Comment: As eed3si9n posted, much like boost::iostreams filter. But I was wondering if it would be a good design to do it oneself by passing a previously opened stream to your custom class constructor derived from public std::streambuf or with some other approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used this but boost's [filtering_stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html) may help.

As an example I found [a mailing list post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/02/133679.php) with [indent.hpp](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/att-133679/indent.hpp), which implements an output filter that indents outputs:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out; 
indent_filter::push(out,2); 
out.push(std::cout);
```

> And use it like so:

```
out << "Hello Filter!\n" 
    << indent_in 
    << "this is\n" 
    << "indented\n" 
    << indent_out 
    << "until here\n" 
    ;
```

> Which will result in output:

```
Hello Filter! 
  this is 
  indented 
until here
```