# Are there good examples of good C++ I/O usage

Tags: c++, stl, io

I am heavily involved in doing I/O in C++ (currently using it for printing headers, tables, some data alignments), and wonder about it proper/great usage in either open source projects or general examples/nippets

I use things such:

```
cout.setf(ios::right,ios::jyustified);
cout<<std::setw()

std::copy (vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::osteam_iterator<const Foo *>
              std::cout,"\n");  //provided I have  operator <<  in/for Foo

locale mylocale(""); 
cout.imbue( mylocale );
```

I don't like my current implementation, as I have a lot of forced `(\t)` and `spaces` to ensure correct indentation. Hence I want to see how I/O is used by top notch professionals.

Comment: printing where to? paper? console only? screen?

Comment: I do it to the screen, but interested in both, files console.... paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that's extremely useful is the Boost [IO state saver library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html). This provides (in particular) a clean way to deal with "sticky" flags.

I tend to agree with David Seiler though -- very few people will be happy with output that's pure text in a single font, etc., that you get by writing just text. HTML, however, is quite easy to generate. RAII, however, can work nicely with fixed-structure documents to ensure that you always generate properly nested tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format data in some easy-to-read way, consider emitting some kind of structured document format (e.g. html or pdf) instead of pure text-plus-spaces-and-tabs.  That problem isn't C++ I/O specific, and can't really be solved with clever use of `<stdio>`.

Answer (score 1):

For the indentation part of your question: The concept of "filter" (as implemented, for example, in the Boost.IOStreams library) is pretty useful and powerful in this respect. For an example, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818947/chaining-c-streams/819004#819004).